# How can i center image in any div in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: The Output]

How can i center image in any div in HTML & CSS ?

I have a nav bar that uses images as links for other pages, the nav bar is multiple divs each has an image and anther div contains a words, how can I center this img in the div

The CSS:

```
#Nav
{           
  height:  150px; 
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#Nav ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
#Nav li
{
 float: left;
 font-size: 12px; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 letter-spacing: 0; 
 margin: 30px;
}
#Nav a
{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;  
 width: 70px;
 height: 100px;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#Nav a:hover 
{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba (0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
#img img 
{
 align-self: middle; 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
#desc 
{
 margin-top: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

The html:

```
<li> <a target="_blank" href="#"> 

          <div id="img"> <img src="C:/Users/hp1/Desktop/Website/Pictures/Accessories.jpg" alt="Accessories">

            <div id="desc"> Accessories </div> 

          </div> 

 </a> </li>
```

Comment: Do you use margin-left or right?

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh in the img I didn't use margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [align-self is for elements inside a flexbox container](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-self.asp) which is not your case, you can try with `text-align: center;` on `img`.

Or if you wish to go full flexbox, set the img container to:

```
.containerClass {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

With this setup `align-self` on the `img` is not need since `justify-content` on it's container will do.

Comment: Thanks so much, the flexbox container worked well :)

Answer (score 9):

**You need to change your CSS for image like below:-**

```
#img img 
{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can see [Many Demos](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html) Here-

Comment: Perfect solution. Not always we have access to parent class.

Answer (score 2):

**Flexbox** to the rescue:

```css
.parent {
  width:200px; height:200px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  
  display: flex;            /* Make it flex */
  flex-direction: column;   /* wrap children elements to columns */
  align-items: center;      /* Center children horizontally */
  justify-content: center;  /* Center children vertically */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent ">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/cf5">
  <p>Green-ish</p>
</div>

<div class="parent ">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/5fc">
  <p>Blue-ish</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked well and gave me the result I wanted  :)

Answer (score 0):

`align-self: center;` is valid, `align-self: middle;` is not valid.

However, you can probably achieve what you're wanting with `text-align: center;`. Despite it being an image, you can still center using text-align as images are, by default, inline elements just like text.

```
#img img 
{
 align-self: center; 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

OR

```
#img img 
{
 text-align: center; 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I tried text-align, align-self and align-item but still nothing work :/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the nature of div to table then make its align to center like this

```
 #img img 
{
display:table;
 align: center; 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```